# Tired of writing non-immediate .so when linking an EXE, how to get relief?

Tags: linux, gcc

I think there should have been a best practice on this issue in the industry, so I ask it here.

This question is about linking shared library(.so) to an executable, with gcc on Linux. But let me start with Windows.

Assume I am developing A.EXE , B.DLL, C1.DLL . The dependency is

```
A -> B -> C1
```

which means: A calls API from B, and B implements itself by calling API from C1. A does not call API in C1 directly.

You know, when linking A.EXE (using Visual C++) , I only have to list B.lib (import lib) as A's link-component(in makefile); C1 does not have to appear in A's makefile. So one day I'd like to replace C1 with C2 for better implementation of B, **I do not have to change A's makefile because of C1's replacement.**

That's great because it follows the rational idea: The makefile only refers to things it directly relates to. With this convenience, people tends to write DLL instead of LIB on Windows -- I think so.

Now I turn to gcc on linux. With the same dependency scenario, **in A's makefile, I have to explicitly list C1 or C2 as link-component,** like this:

```
gcc -o A a1.o a2.o -lB -lC1
```

So frustrating, imagine you have ten projects A1, A2, ... A10 calling into B, you have to modify ten makefiles to make the shift from C1 to C2.

How to get a relief ?

Comment: You don't have DLLs on Linux. You have shared object libraries, which are different beasts.

Comment: Thanks. I referred to Windows DLL just because I need to cite an expected behavior I knew.

Comment: But you need to understand that (and how) `.so` files are not behaving on Linux like `.dll` are on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `libB` depends on `libC` (`ldd libB.so`) ; `libB` should have been compiled with something like `gcc -o libB.so -shared -fPIC *.c -L/path/to/libC -lC -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/libC`.

Note that `libB.so` needs to be compiled with `-rpath` in order to be able to locate `libC.so`, or use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (the `ldd` command mentioned above must not show `libC.so => not found`)

Comment: I am not sure you have to pass `-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined`; I never do.

Answer (score 3):

When linking some shared library `libfoo.so` you can link it with another shared library `libbar.so`:

```
  gcc -fPIC -g -Wall -c foo1.c
  gcc -fPIC -g -Wall -c foo2.c
  gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo1.o foo2.o -lbar
```

then when you use `-lfoo` the `libbar.so` will be linked automatically without asking for it.

So you don't have to to explicitly list C1 or C2 as link-component in A's makefile.

<sup>you would have to do that if you had only static libraries `lib*.a`</sup>

So you could build a program with

```
  gcc -Wall -g prog.c -lfoo
```

alone (not mentioning `libbar.so` explicitly).

Try for instance to run `ldd` on the GTK shared library (on my Debian system):

```
  ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
```

I suggest reading [Levine's linker & loader book](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) to understand the difference between Windows `.dll` and Linux `.so`; they are different beasts. Read also the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

You might want (or not) to use [GNU libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/).

BTW, you might also use [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/), which would give the dependencies...

Comment: I tried it on opensuse 11.3. Your ``gcc -Wall -g prog.c -lfoo`` will fail with ld's ``warning: libbar.so, needed by ./libfoo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)``. In order to succeed, I have to write linker command ``gcc -Wall -g prog.c -lfoo -Wl,-rpath-link,.``, WHICH MEANS, I STILL NEED libbar.so WHEN GENERATING main. ISN'T IT A BURDEN compared to Windows? Any relief?